# How do i align a background color for a text to an image?

Tags: css

im quite new to coding... and im making a portfolio that contains all the projects ive currently done... and i want to align the text background color to the image to sort of have a flushed in effect or somehting

```
    .project-tile{
        padding: 10px;
        width: 30%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .project-tile img{
        max-height: 300px;
        max-width: 300px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.575);
    }
    .project-tile a{
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-size: 23px;
        background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.575);
        display: grid;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        height: 40px;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

html

```
    <section id="projects">
        <h2>Here are few of my projects ive been working on</h2>
        <div class="project-tile">
            <a href="https://codepen.io/Leuqas/full/gOXLGoE">Tribute Page</a>
            <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/940847175867457547/940848284073885726/unknown.png" alt="picture">
        </div>
        <div class="project-tile">
            <a href="https://codepen.io/Leuqas/full/PoOWXWp">HTML Documentation Page</a>
            <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/940847175867457547/940847191801618442/unknown.png" alt="picture">
        </div>
        <div class="project-tile">
            <a href="https://codepen.io/Leuqas/full/xxPRMPX">Product Landing Page</a>
            <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/940847175867457547/940849497288880178/unknown.png" alt="picture">
        </div>
    </section>
```

this are my current codes [and what it looks like(picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LsIg.png)

Comment: paste your html code. it'll give us more information to suggest you some solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can test this.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height:100px;
  background-color:gray
}

.container-child{
 background-color:green;
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 display:flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="container-child">text</div>
 <div class="container-child">text</div>
 <div class="container-child">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap all the divs in one div (I set its id to "wrapper") and set its display to flex. (didn't change anything else in your code)

```css
#wrapper {
    display: flex; //<<----- The newly added
}

.project-tile{
    padding: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.project-tile img{
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.575);
}
.project-tile a{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 23px;
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.575);
    display: grid;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="projects">
        <h2>Here are few of my projects ive been working on</h2>
        <div id="wrapper"> <!----The newly added------->
            <div class="project-tile">
                <a href="https://codepen.io/Leuqas/full/gOXLGoE">Tribute Page</a>
                <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/940847175867457547/940848284073885726/unknown.png" alt="picture">
            </div>
            <div class="project-tile">
                <a href="https://codepen.io/Leuqas/full/PoOWXWp">HTML Documentation Page</a>
                <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/940847175867457547/940847191801618442/unknown.png" alt="picture">
            </div>
            <div class="project-tile">
                <a href="https://codepen.io/Leuqas/full/xxPRMPX">Product Landing Page</a>
                <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/940847175867457547/940849497288880178/unknown.png" alt="picture">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: im sorry i dont think i explained what i need well enough... what i actualy need is to line up the background color of my <a> tag to each image.,, refer to the picture i atached (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LsIg.png)